# Bash aliases/functions and command line options

Tags: bash, command-line, alias, bashrc

I want to set an alias to start nedit together with command line option -noautosave (due to text files up to 500MB). What seemed to be easy:

```
alias nn="nedit -noautosave $1 &"
```

just raises some error *"Permission denied"* of a different file and another error about *unexpected EOF while looking for matching "'"* and *"unexpected end of file"*.

One solution I found after a Google Search would be to check the quotes, but I can't see any possible errors with them.

I also tried declaring a function:

```
function nn () { nedit -noautosave $1 &}
```

which also failed with same errors.

Comment: Does `nedit -noautosave` work just from the shells? The function does not seem to be the problem to me.

Comment: Well, thanks, I forgot to mention that. I tried to do it that way (aka manually), and there is no problem at all, autosave is turned off and nedit is working as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to run `nedit` with `-noautosave` when one of the files to be opened is larger than a given size, try this (I am using 100M but you can set your own size limit):

```
function nn() { 
    big=0;
    let big+=$(find "$@" -size +100M|wc -l)
    if [ $big -gt 0 ]; then
     nedit -noautosave -- "$@" &
    else
     nedit -- "$@" &
    fi
}
```

From `man nedit`:

```
   --  Treats all subsequent arguments as file names,
       even if they start with a dash.  This is so NEdit
       can access files that begin with the dash
       character.
```

Comment: Would also work with `let big+=$(find "$@" -size +100 M|wc -l)` (no need for the `for` loop).

Comment: You can even do `if [ ! -z $(find "$@" -size +100M) ];then`

Comment: @JosephR. yes the `for` was there cause I had started writing it using a different approach (I was trying to use `&&` and `find`'s exit codes but they don't work that way) and the `for` stayed. Answer edited, thanks.

Comment: @terdon I don't know exactly why, but your solution works for me, although the syntax is the same as in slm's answer. Weird... Anyway thanks for your answer, especially because it is very handy to automatically switch the parameters depending on the size of the file. I would love to upvote, but my reputation is too low, yet ;)

Comment: @SoumVhon you're welcome. Please remember to accept one of the answers (either mine or slm's from whose answer I shamelessly copied) so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass arguments into an `alias`. You'll have to use a `function`, so you were on the right track. You just had a typo in your use of the `function` command. Either of these will do, however:

```
$ nn () { nedit -noautosave -- "$@" & }
```

-or-

```
$ function nn() { nedit -noautosave -- "$@" & }
```

If you need to remove it, use the `unset` command, i.e. `unset -f nn`.

Also I'd use `"$@"` instead of `$1`, on the off chance that you want to open a series of files in this manner.

*excerpt from `bash` man page*

```
@      Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one.  When the 
       expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a 
       separate word.  That is, "$@" is equivalent  to  "$1" "$2" ...  If 
       the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of 
       the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original 
       word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
       part of the original word.  When there are no positional parameters,
       "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).
```

#### Example

```
$ function nn() { nedit -noautosave -- "$@" & }

$ nn ~/.bashrc 
[3] 19830
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this won't work for me. The same errors appear. What do the separate '--' stand for? Perhaps the error lies in some settings of my bash environment...

Comment: Nedit is installed. I wrote a similar function that just opens nedit with the specified file (just to have the '&'), and this works pretty well. But when opening a 500MB text file and nedit saves after every 80 or so strokes, editing can become very annoying. A workaround would be to increase the amount of strokes after nedit autosaves, but this would be a global setting.

Comment: @SoumVhon - This is sounding more like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your real issue, `nedit` slows down when `-autosave` is enabled after some period of time?

Comment: I see what you try pointing to. But there is no problem with nedit's autosave capability nor it's speed (which is, when it comes to saving, only limitated by network and/or hard drive speed), I just want to create a program shortcut/alias that uses the -noautosave parameter to disable autosave completely (enabled by default). Only when there is now way of creating such a shortcut (and that seems to be the case on my system, even when I try your suggested solution), I either have to alter nedits configuration to get the behavior I am looking for, or just do it manually every time I need it.

Comment: Oh, just in case, I don't want to switch off autosave completely, just sometimes when I have to handle big files. If there is a smarter/easier way to achieve this goal, I would be happy to hear.

Comment: @SoumVhon - OK I just wanted to check if there was something more fundamental. One more thing to try would be to completely disable your .bashrc/.bash_profile from being included in your setup temporarily, like this: `bash --norc`. Then try doing the `function ..` in that shell, this will eliminate any customizations you may have in those files that are impeding us.

Answer (score 1):

If the whole point of the alias is to apply the `-noautosave` option to any file you edit, then

```
alias nn='nedit -noautosave'
```

should be enough. You can then use it as

```
nn your_file &
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this one is working, although is was hoping for a solution that uses the '&' so that I don't have to type it by myself :)

Comment: @SoumVhon In that case, an alias is definitely not the answer and you should go with slm's solution after figuring out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> alias nn="nedit -noautosave $1 &"
> ```

The variable expansion is interpreted inside double quotes. If you ran that from your `.bashrc` or at your shell's command line, there were no positional parameters (they would be the parameters passed to the shell), so `$1` expanded to the empty string, and the alias value is `nnedit -noautosave &`. Therefore, when you ran `nn /path/to/file.txt`, that was expanded to `nnedit -noautosave & /path/to/file.txt`. The error message “Permission denied” was because `/path/to/file.txt` is not executable.

You could have used `alias nn='nedit -noautosave $1 &'` to prevent the expansion and retain `$1` inside the alias. However this wouldn't have worked any better, because aliases don't take arguments, they are substituted in place. So `$1` would have been replaced by the first positional parameter at the time the alias was expanded, which is no better than before.

> ```
> function nn () { nedit -noautosave $1 &}
> ```

That's basically correct. If you got the same errors as before, it's because the alias `nn` was still defined, and an alias takes precedence over a function of the same name. Use `unalias nn` to undefine the alias.

The function should be written this way:

```
function nn () { nedit -autosave "$@" & }
```

The double quotes are necessary in case there are spaces or wildcard characters in the file name. Using `"$@"` instead of `"$1"` lets you pass multiple arguments.

Comment: if you wanted to you could've morphed my answer into this one if you wanted to. I understand it's a bordeline call whether to do this but now we have 2 answers on this question that are very similar. Let me know your thoughts on this, not just for here but for others A's too in the future.

Comment: @slm Uh? Your answer doesn't explain why his alias and his function (which was correct) failed. The intersection of our answers is about two sentences (“you can't use an alias” and “use `"$@"` instead of `$1`”).

Comment: OK. Was just a thought.

Comment: @Gilles I understand now that aliases are limited when it comes to arguments, parameters and variables, and therefore a function should be used in my case. What I don't get is why it fails when I define it the way you recommend. If I don't define an alias with the same name at all, I don't need to unalias it, correct? So there should be no interference from the very beginning. Most likely, the problem lies somewhere else, e.g. global bash settings (workplace computer, huge network).

Comment: @SoumVhon If you haven't defined an alias with the same name, the function should work. There may be some weird setting somewhere that causes strange behavior, but it really looks like the alias is still being invoked if you get the same errors. Run `set -x` first to see what commands bash runs. Try without the rest of your `.bashrc`.